# Can't access Modern Warfare API with jquery post

Tags: jquery, api

I want to pull my modern warfare stats via their api. When I use the following URL in my browser I get a json file back.

https://my.callofduty.com/api/papi-client/stats/cod/v1/title/mw/platform/battle/gamer/LordNoodles%2321599/profile/type/mp

But when I use the follwing jquery post method

```
$.post("sameURL").done(function (data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

I get this error message: 
message: "Not permitted: not authenticated"
type: "com.activision.mt.common.stdtools.exceptions.NoStackTraceException"

It's odd, because I'm clearly logged in.

Comment: I get the same error when I click your link because I'm not signed in to that website. You need to make an AJAX request to first authenticate yourself and (I assume) receive an authentication token which you can then use in the headers of subsequent requests.

Comment: The link I used was a dummy. I changed it to be the real thing. Would you mind try again? The guy I got the info from said this needs no authentication.

Comment: This is what I get: `{"status":"error","data":{"type":"com.activision.mt.common.stdtools.exceptions.NoStackTraceException","message":"Not permitted: not authenticated"}}`. In any case the API requires authentication. If you check the documentation I'm sure there will be a guide on how to get an access token, and where it should go in later requests - normally it's in the headers

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan unfortunately, there is no "official" documentation even though the API is public. Anyone trying to work on this is basically grabbing any endpoint(s) they can from the web app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to log in with a CSRF token and then use retrieved data as input for the API call.

Step-by-step:

1. GET call for CSRF token
2. POST call to login using CSRF token and Activison credentials (store cookies)
3. GET call for API https://my.callofduty.com/api/papi-client/stats/cod/v1/title/mw/platform/battle/gamer/LordNoodles%2321599/profile/type/mp with cookies from previous step

Feel free to check the article https://somethingneeddoing.medium.com/how-to-call-rest-api-with-csrf-login-and-security-tokens-node-js-6685615b324e where it's described in more detail.